# How can I build a SharePoint 2010 package using command line?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, sharepoint-2010

I have a Visual Studio 2010 SharePoint project. If I choose 'Package' from the project menu, a .wsp file is generated. How can I invoke the same build from command line (i.e. what /target is required for MSBuild)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got it to work, finally. The tricky part is the fact that the SharePoint targets do not exist when MSBuild loads the `.sln` file, you have to load the individual `.csproj` files.

```
set msbuild="C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe"
set config=Debug
set outdir="C:\out\"
%msbuild% /p:Configuration=%config% /m ../My.SharePoint.Project/My.SharePoint.Projectcsproj /t:Package /p:BasePackagePath=%outdir%
```

Comment: Is there any practical difference between using `/t:Package` versus `/t:Build /p:IsPackaging=True`?

Answer (score 3):

This is also a useful document here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ff622991.aspx

> "To generate packages when building in
>   TFS 2010, set the parameter
>   /p:IsPackaging=True on MSBuild"

Answer (score 1):

Also to package project with msbuild you can use target **Package**:

- Define new target "BuildAndPackage"

  > ```
  > <Target Name="BuildAndPackage">
  >   <CallTarget Targets="Build"/>
  >   <CallTarget Targets="Package"/>
  > </Target>
  > ```
- Use new target in build process:

  > ```
  > <Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="BuildAndPackage">
  > ```

But this approach not recommended because it may cause errors in TFS Build process..

Answer (score 0):

Set the MSBuild's verbosity to 'maximum' and you should see what is called from the build console.

In VS2010 of course :)

Comment: I set it to 'Diagnostic' before, the amount of noise it generated made it impossible to find anything.