# How to create wsp package from powershell

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint, powershell

Please help, how to create wsp package from powershell?
I know how to build solution, but I don't know how to emulate command Package, which exists for WebPart projects in project item context menu.

Thank you!

Comment: A .wsp file is just a cab file with a renamed extension.  They are usually created using Visual Studio or http://wspbuilder.codeplex.com/

Beyond that, I don't understand your question.

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726835/how-can-i-build-a-sharepoint-2010-package-using-command-line
(assuming you were talking about sharepoint 2010)

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you want.

```
set-alias msbuild C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe
msbuild /t:package **[.csproj file]**
```

Regards,

Pedro