# Create wsp-files with msbuild

Tags: sharepoint-2010, msbuild, wsp

When I rightclick on a sharepoint project and select "deploy" a wsp file gets generated.

I now want to automate the buildprocsses. I already use nant to call MsBuild. This builds my csproj-file.

How can I get from this to my wsp files? I read some articles that talked about a ddf file but I don't see one in my solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I build a SharePoint 2010 package using command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726835/how-can-i-build-a-sharepoint-2010-package-using-command-line)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
set msbuild="C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe"
set config=Debug
set outdir="C:\out\"
%msbuild% /p:Configuration=%config% /m  project.csproj /t:Package /p:BasePackagePath=%outdir%
```