# WSPBuilder doesn't add all Files to manifest.xml correctly

Tags: sharepoint, deployment, sharepoint-2010, wsp, wspbuilder

I use WSPBuilder to create WSP-Files from my Sharepoint projects. Some of them contain Files in special folders like "Layouts" that need to be deployed.

When I use VS2010's ability to create a wsp-File using the "deploy" command, the wsp contains a manifest.xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Solution xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/" SolutionId="2d5da9c1-0fe4-4ff8-9f4d-c025cf9bc2c1" SharePointProductVersion="14.0">
  <Assemblies>
    <Assembly Location="Tools.dll" DeploymentTarget="GlobalAssemblyCache" />
  </Assemblies>
  <TemplateFiles>
    <TemplateFile Location="Layouts\GetThumbnail.aspx" />
  </TemplateFiles>
</Solution>
```

But when I use WSPBuilder the `<TemplateFiles>` section is completely missing. That is how I call WSPBuilder:

```
WspBuilder. tools.csprog -buildSafeControls false
```

Any idea how to get those templatefiles into the manifest.xml wit WSPBuilder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You should not use the old WSPBuilder tool to build SharePoint 2010 packages.** Use either Visual Studio or MSBuild if you need automate the process:

```
set msbuild="C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe"
set config=Debug
set outdir="C:\out\"
%msbuild% /p:Configuration=%config% /m ../My.SharePoint.Project/My.SharePoint.Projectcsproj /t:Package /p:BasePackagePath=%outdir%
```

More information: [How can I build a SharePoint 2010 package using command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726835/how-can-i-build-a-sharepoint-2010-package-using-command-line)

Comment: Damn! You don't even guess how much work I put into that solution cause all resources I found were about manually creating ddf - files and so on. Maybe those resources were just too old. 
Worked fine, thanks!

Comment: @MaxKlinger This is how SharePoint 2007 packages had to be built. It was complicated and many custom solutions were created - that's why you found so many resources describing creating the DDF files manually, etc.